# Angular 2 aot build - require issue

Tags: image, angular, typescript, angular-cli

When building my application aot via angular-cli

i.e. **(ng build --aot --prod)**

I am receiving the following error:

```
..app>ng build --prod --aot
10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active Error encountered 
resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'require',
function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function
or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol
appComponent in ..app.component.ts, resolving symbol AppComponent 
in ..app.component.ts
```

My component looks like:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-component',
template: `
 ...
<div class="centered">
    <img [src]="logo">
</div>
....
`,
styles: [require('./app-component.component.css')]
})

export class LoginComponent {

private logo = require('./logo.png');
...
}
```

Is there any workaround available?

Comment: function call is not supported, add a reference to a function

Comment: Can you provide me with a snippet? I tried to create a new component and do something like: export var logo = require('./logo.png'); but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think require statements are allowed with AOT compilation. They're unnecessary anyways.

Comment: According to the error log they are not allowed, indeed. If they are unnecessary, how can one bind an image to an img src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Make this changes so the path is absolute to the application root

The component's template:

```
<div class="centered">
    <img src="{{logo}}">
</div>
```

The component's class:

```
private logo = '/images/logo.png';
```

Comment: It seems that it does not work at all, because the path is relevant to the base url, i.e. the response is an expected GET http://localhost:4200/logo.png 404 (Not Found)